# No puedo actualizar el origen de datos en VS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, linq

[image: problema con el origen de datos]
 Tengo un proyecto en visual studio professional 2012 en donde utilizo el linq cuando agrego un campo a la base de datos (en SQLServer) en el linq aparece el campo nuevo en la imagen que agrege tengo el campo `cuenta_sobrante` pero no actualiza el origen de datos de la tabla `cuenta_bancos`, la solucion que encontre era hacerlo manual con el boton  "configurar origen de datos con el asistente" pero me aparece desactivado. ¿que puedo hacer para que vuelva a actualizar de forma automatica el origen de datos?? es un error de visual studio? hay algo en el codigo que impide que se actualice?

Comment: Intentaste darle en actualizar, la cuarta opción, en la ventana orígenes de datos?

Comment: justo estaba por escribir eso @Dev.Joel :D

Comment: si ya, también elimine y volví a crear el objeto y recompile la solucion

Comment: Intentar esta solución : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-do-i-update-a-linq-to-sql-dbml-file

Comment: En realidad el medio de persistencia que usas ya esta obsoleto, deberias evaluar pasar a Entity Framework y no seguir usando linq to sql

Comment: [https://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/] que opinan de esta herramienta, aun hay q pagar por ella o ya no? funcionaria para resolver este problema??

Answer (score 1):

No intentaste haciendo uso del plugin [SqlMetalPlus](https://sqlmetalplus.codeplex.com/)

[Updating a Linq to SQL dbml file](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/updating-linq-to-sql-dbml-file.html)

creo que este podria ayudarte en la actualizacion del modelo